# If statement inside For loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am developing a batch script to make changes to multiple servers that may or may not contain a particular subfolder under D:\apps\domain.  There are multiple combinations of possible domain subfolders.  My logic requires:
if domain\folder1 exists then do command1
if domain\folder2 exists then do command2
and so on

I am using the following...

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%Z in ('dir /a:D /b "D:\apps\domain"') do (
if %%Z="PGBWAHD_NA" 
command1
```

but get syntax errors on first IF statement.
Error message ....
=PGBWAHD_NA was unexpected at this time.
D:\apps\hawk_schtasks>if /I %Z=PGBWAHD_NA
The subfolder PGBWAHD_NA does exist, but the script errors and quits.

Answer (score 2):

you rather need:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%Z in ('dir /a:D /b "D:\apps\domain"') do (
  if "%%~Z" == "PGBWAHD_NA" (
  command1
 )
)
```

in batch files valid comparisons are `==` , `EQU` , `LSS` , `LEQ` , `GTR` , `GEQ` and quotes are also evaluated.